# C# logical comparison with || or &&

Tags: c#, arrays, logical-operators

I have a while loop which goes through the string until it reaches multiple chars.

```
while (json[z-2] != 's' && json[z] != ':')
{ z++; }
```

I thought `&&` means AND, and this was supposed to loop until it reached a place in the string where `s` and `:` characters were 1 char apart but it stopped on the first `:`.

Tried using `||` and it worked, but I want to know why.

Hope this is all clear for you.

Comment: *chars were near* none of this means near? It's not clear what you actually want here

Comment: `!(a && b)` is equivalent to `!a || !b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just logic: whole expression combined by `and` is `true` only when both parts are `true`.

So when your loop met first `:` character, expression is `false` and loop has been stopped.

Based on your description, your code should look like

```
while (!(json[z-2] == 's' && json[z] == ':'))
{ z++; }
```

or equivalentely

```
while (json[z-2] != 's' || json[z] != ':')
{ z++; }
```

Comment: So using `or`, loop isnt stopped until both of them is `false`?

Comment: @EvaldasGrigaitis Yes, since expression combined by `or` is `true` when any part of it is `true`. It looks like you should refresh your knowledge of logical operators. ;)

Comment: @EvaldasGrigaitis Think about it: if `json[z] == ':'` is true, then `json[z-2] != 's' && json[z] != ':'` will be false.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there are 2 kinds of operators:

- **Shortcut operators**: `&&`, `||`
- **Bitwise operators**: `&`, `|`

The **shortcut operators** skip the rest of the expression as soon as the result of the operation is clear, this means:

- for AND: it evaluates to `false` if any part of the expression evaluates to `false`
- for OR: it evaluates to `true` if any part of the expression evaluates to `true`

As opposed to this behaviour, the **bitwise operators** always evaluate the entire expression. For most cases, **shortcut operators** are doing nicely and can save time if complex expressions are evaluated very often (e.g. inside of a large loop).

But sometimes, you have to use the **bitwise operators**, especially if the functions being called have side-effects (they are used for binary bitwise calculations as well, but that is not discussed here).

**Example:**

```
int countEven = 0;
int countOdd = 0;

bool isEven(int x)
{
    countEven++;
    return (x % 1)==0;
}


bool isOdd(int x)
{
    countOdd++;
    return (x % 1) != 0;
}
```

Now if you have

```
    var a=5;
    var expression = (a==4) && (isEven(2) || isOdd(1));
    Console.WriteLine($"Expression result: {expression}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Even calls: {countEven}, Odd calls: {countEven} ");
```

You will get `0` for `countEven` as well as for `countOdd`, because the functions `isEven(2)` and `isOdd(1)` are never called.

Change that to:

```
    var expression = (a==4) & (isEven(2) | isOdd(1));
```

and the functions will be invoked, so `countEven` and `CountOdd` are being incremented.

Of course, side effects (as shown above) should be avoided, but I hope the difference is clear now.